# The Start menu no longer shows up when I press the Start button

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 Pro.

Everything was working, but today when I pressed the Start button, nothing happened. The Start menu is not showing.

I have restarted the PC several times, but it's the same situation. What can I do?

Comment: Run DISM and SFC in that order then post the results.

Comment: Can you give me the full commands that I should run ?

Comment: Several solutions in http://superuser.com/questions/1000458/my-windows-10-doesnt-show-the-desktop-and-start-menu?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start Button won't show Start Menu on Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1056215/start-button-wont-show-start-menu-on-windows-10)

Comment: @Ramhound  My question is asked 5 months ago , so it's older than the question that you are referring that is asked 1 month ago. Anyway this question has a TESTED answer posted below. And I don't understand why this question has a -2 down votes , and the DUPLICATE Question has up votes ? If 2 questions are duplicate means that both are almost the same.

Comment: The other question has more details.  The other answer has more details.  So from my perspective the other question is a better candidate, for future duplicates, then this question.  I don't care about the age question to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command has worked for me on PowerShell:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```