# Start menu is not sorted alphabetically

Tags: windows-10-v1511

I'm using Windows 10 build 1511.

Today I've noticed a problem with items on Start Menu-All Apps.

I have installed several adobe applications, and after installations, all the shortcuts have the word "Adobe" at the beginning of their names, so on Start Menu -All apps, all these shortcuts are under "A" Section.

I have renamed all these shortcuts, by removing the word "Adobe" and leaving the same the other part. I have restarted my windows, and after I was expecting that these shortcuts not to be still under "A" section.
But these shortcuts were again under "A" section.

Illustrator, InDesign, Dreamweaver... all these shortcuts although their names doesn't begin with "A" anymore, are still under "A" section.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I do not know windows 10, but i do know windows registry, and for many OS versions now there has been key items in the registry found by searching "MenuOrder" for the start menu and for favorites. Ccleaner also has always had a cleanup items for clearing that (most people might not even know why).  We would regularly toss the MenuOrder items (and everything under) to rearrange alphabetically, vrses staying where it was put.    I would wonder if this ordering in the registry still exists in 10, and could be cleared to re-sort in your situation?  Using Ccleaner was always a 'safer' way.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this solution will work for you on Windows 10; it works for me on Windows 7:

Click the start menu -> navigate to the list that isn't alphabetically sorted -> right click anything in the list -> click "Sort by Name."

And yes, I've also seen a non-alphabetic sort of the start menu items persist through reboots. I imagine Windows does this because it's possible some folks prefer that the applications be listed by most recently added.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work on windows 10 build 1511

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer - I am not sure if this may have any unexpected results - I've used it and have had no problems but this method involves re-registering a system package.

I've created a test shortcut `DTest`, which I will rename, and I believe this is the problem you're having:

[image]

Now renamed `Test`

[image]

The start menu data seems to be held in the process ShellExperienceHost. I can't seem to find any way to simply reset the data for this, so I fixed it be re-registering this component.

Open `Powershell` as an administrator

Enter the command `Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppXManifest.xml"`

Et voila:

[image]

[image]

As I said at the start, I don't know if this has any negative side effects, I haven't noticed any as of yet, but it seems a drastic way to force a refresh. I believe the data it uses should be stored in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy` - but I couldn't find anything that looked too relevant.

Comment: After executing your command , my windows is restarted , and now is not starting , after going to logo screen , restart.

Comment: @alex Windows restarted as soon as you ran the command? That shouldn't happen - It's actually the [same command](http://superuser.com/questions/996658) you've run before, but specifically the part that handles the Start Menu instead of reinstalling every package.

Comment: The command on the link that you've posted , has resolved that problem. Do you think that command include your command posted here ? so can that command fix this problem ? And yes your command has restarted the system.

Comment: @alex The command in the other question reregisters every system app, the command in this question reregisters only the ShellExperienceHost app. Both of them would reregister that one component. It may be worth trying the command in your answer again, yes.